# How do I post in BitcoinTalk?

Tags: bitcointalk

I created an account with Bitcoin talk, logged in, and don't see any option to reply to existing threads or create new ones.

I have the ability to "watch", "notify", etc. but I don't see an option that allows me to reply.

I also checked the "My Profile" tab to see if there is any validation I need to do to authorize my account.

In addition, I've also logged out and logged back into the forum using different browsers.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think rules have changed. Below is the latest rules from(https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=15958.0):

> Due to a mass of trolling, only established posters are able to post
>   in non-newbie sections. You are considered "established" if you have
>   made one post and then waited 4 hours. This post must be substantial:
>   at least several sentences.
>
> If you have really good posts, you can post a request for preemptive
>   whitelisting in the appropriate topic.
>
> Also:
>   - Newbies cannot upload their own avatars.
>   - You must have made one post in order to send PMs.
>   - You need 10 posts to put a link in your signature.
>
> Note that it may take up to 10 minutes for your PM or posting
>   permissions to be granted. (The system automatically checks every 10
>   minutes and promotes people as appropriate.)

Answer (score 5):

[Newbie restrictions](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=15958.0) - you need to be logged in for 4 hours and post 5 posts to the Newbie section in order to be allowed elsewhere.

Comment: Or, as, is described in Colin Dean's answer below, request to be whitelisted.

Answer (score 3):

BitcoinTalk has a [newbie policy](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=15958.0) that requires users to have completed these criteria in order to post in forums other than the [newbie forum](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=39.0):

- 4 hours online
- 5 posts

If you've already made significant contributions to the Bitcoin community outside of BitcoinTalk, then you can seek [whitelisting](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=15911.0), or excusal from the newbie policy.