# Why can't I participate on bitcointalk.org?

Tags: bitcointalk

I just created an account and spend a frustrating hour reading help menus and trying to figure out how to post or reply to posts.

None of the buttons -- New Topic, Reply, Quote -- seem to be showing up.  Is there a verification step that I skipped?

I'm logged it.  I get the "hello [user]" message on top.

Comment: See [this for an answer](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5750/1878)

Answer (score 9):

You should first make some posts on the [Newbies](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=39.0) forum. [This post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=177133.0) explains the restrictions.

> **Newbie Restrictions** You can only post in the Newbie and Local
>   sub-forums till you have 5 posts and at least 4 hours on the forum. 
>   The other two restrictions are you need 1 post to be able to send a PM
>   and 10 posts to put a link in your sig.

Comment: You beat me to answering this one. Argh low hanging points....