# Can't post on bitcointalk.org

Tags: bitcoind, bitcointalk

I've done some research and understand that I'm supposed to post in a newbie forum and wait a while, as a newly registered user.

But I can't seem to find the newbie forum.  Does anyone know which top-level forum it lives under?

In fact, no matter where I am, there's always a big banner on my screen saying I can't post.  When I click "How to Enable Posting," it says there's an error: bitcoind is offline.

I tried to find a way to contact some staff member.  No luck.  In fact, my private messaging section says I'm not allowed to send messages.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: @NickODell That's crazy! The OP in the BCT post is lamenting the "fascist" BitcoinTalk forum for stopping his "fair Ponzi scheme": http://imgur.com/WDYRNUx (top right corner)

Comment: @NickODell is thus actually a duplicate? "Units of evil" is news to me

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie Ah, my bad. The newbie restriction is a duplicate, but the "units of evil" is not.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your account has "units of evil" which require you to pay money to remove them. Bitcoin, the program used to accept these payments, is down. See also https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=953005.msg10434122#msg10434122

You also have restrictions on your account due to being a new user. See [Why can't I participate on bitcointalk.org?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11089/why-cant-i-participate-on-bitcointalk-org?lq=1)